# Firebase Google Sign-In will not work (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I was originally trying to add Firebase Authentication Google Sign-in to my app. When that didn't work out, I decided to just try Firebase's official Quickstart app. I downloaded it, imported it into Android Studio and followed all their directions. It still won't work.

What happens is I'll click the "*Sign in*" button, a dialog will come up where I select my profile, and then just nothing. Debugging, I've found that the `onActivityResult result.isSuccess()` method returns false, and I don't know where to go from here.

Checklist of frequently offered solutions:

- I have added the Firebase JSON file to the quickstart app (after creating a new project)
- I have provided the SHA-1 code
- Firebase Auth/Google Repo/Everything is the latest version
- I have hit the "enable google sign in" toggle button in the Firebase console

Device details:

- Android device: Samsung-SM-G530A
- Android OS version: 5.1.1
- Google Play Services version: 10.2.0
- Firebase/Play Services SDK version: 10.2.0

My code is theirs, I haven't modified anything. Found [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth).

Edit: So, I got their quickstart working. I think it was a problem with my SHA-1 code on firebase. Now though I have a new problem in my app...whenever I call FirebaseAuth I get an error like this:

```
error:cannot access zzbql
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbql not found
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileFacebookDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Edit 2: OK so now everything's screwed up! On any xml/layout file I look at there are all sorts of errors about classes not being instantiated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AppCompatTextHelper
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:58)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:40)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:72)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:150)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you log into the google web service from the same device?  Just checking its not a networking problem.

Comment: By Google web service do you mean just usual google apps like gmail/google? I can log into those

Comment: Yes, that was the thought.  But I suppose you could have some kind of firewall on your phone/wifi that is blocking access to the firebase authentication server (unlikely -- its probably just using https).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright everyone thanks for the help.

The original problem's solution was that my SHA-1 fingerprint was not correct in Firebase.

My edit's solution was to DECREASE the version of com.google.android.gms from 10.2.0 to 10.0.1

Weird, but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) 
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity /, this / OnConnectionFailedListener*/)
.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso) 
.build();
```

Add `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` at the end of above line of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the end of its initialization"?

Comment: @therealccarter edited my answer to make it more meaningful for you.

Comment: @cullub it connects client with Google play services. Read more here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient

Answer (score 0):

Suggested direction from here is to get more debugging info on the problem.  Possibly using:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBU‌​G)
```

And then look at the console/logcat output in Android studio.  Check [here](http://How%20to%20test%20android%20apps%20in%20a%20real%20device%20with%20Android%20Studio?) and/or [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) for details.

There are a few answers on the web [like this](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/issues/11) that you may have seen, but without more info on the error, it's hard to know if they apply in your case.

Comment: I've been debugging quite a bit, and if I step through all the lines of code, the place where it fails is when the Google sign in intent is started for activity result, line 142 here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java

Comment: So I'm thinking it must have something to do with either my SHA1 or the google-config.json file. To be totally replicable, I'll re-download firebase's quickstart from github and only follow their directions for google sign in.

Comment: @therealccarter yes that is the most likely.  I was looking for a debug message or the http data (json) that came back from the google service to give you a hint of why the auth failed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help so far, I'll get back to you with that stuff/other updates tomorrow or so