# Cannot access zzbql in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I updated to the latest buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' I got this error when I try to run:

> Error:(103, 37) error: cannot access zzbql class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbql not found

I'm using these Firebase libs:

```
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Can be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355796/firebase-google-sign-in-will-not-work-android ?

Comment: Nope , am unable to compile , the case you suggested is having problems with getting user data back ,  my code is already on the market and working , am able to log in (at least before updating)

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it by downgrading from 10.2.0 to 10.0.1

Comment: @AlejandroMorán This question is already using `10.0.1`...

Comment: Please post the entire dependencies block from your build.gradle so we can see the complete list of libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upgrade your firebase for version 10.2.0

** As of 07.11.2017 it's 11.6.0

Comment: This is the right answer , but why didn't I get a warning of outdated lib as I usually get ?

Comment: I'm using `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'` but the error message doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to solve the problem really is upgrading Firebase to 10.2.0 as in @DenerRocha 's reply.

But you might get the same problem again next time google-play-services is updated. The problem is that the compiler warns you that there's a new google-play services version, but doesn't do the same for Firebase. So keep the following in mind:

When you have this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

Your Firebase will be:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
```

When 10.3.0 is release, you'll have to **update all of them** to 10.3.0

Comment: Adding to this, you can define the version as `String playServicesVersion = '10.2.4'` and then use that for both play services and firebase:
{`compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServicesVersion}"  
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServicesVersion}"`}

Answer (score 0):

I actually downgraded my compile sdk version ,target sdk version to 26 and associated dependencies as well.
I also downgraded my firebase database and ui dependencies as well to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

It worked like charm.

Here is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.e.alcphase222"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'



testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}